# Inserting data from one table to another table values based on column condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to know if there is a way to achieve this.
I have two table, I want to move data from one table to another table.

```
TableA:
ID  Name  Option
----------------------
1  First   Add into box
2  Second  Don't Add
3  Third   Add into box

TableB
ID Name    Option          Status
--------------------------------
1  First   Add into box    Approved 
2  Second  Don't Add       Reject
3  Third   Add into box    Approved
```

I want to insert data from TableA to tableB but tableB have one more column, where the value of it depends on `option` column data.
If column value is `Add into box` then it should be inserted as approved into TableB else `Reject` has to be inserted.

Comment: MySQL and SSMS (SQL Server Management Studio) have no relationship. As it's name suggests, SSMS is for SQL Server, which is a completely different product to MySQL. What RDBMS are you *really* using?

Comment: As for the problem, use a `CASE` expression.

Comment: There is definitely a way to achieve this it's quite trivial but please first tag the correct database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using MSSQL, the below query would work.

```
Insert into TableB (Id,Name, Option, Status) 
select Id,Name, Option, CASE when Option = 'Add into box'  then 'Approved' ELSE 'Rejected' END
From TableA
```

Comment: Hello @Ankitha, Thank you! it worked, didn't know this was that simple.

Comment: @Mike since this appears to be SQL Server, I will tag the correct database. Please make sure you do thisin future.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, Thank you! I was actually confused with these terms: sql-server and MySql and sql.